# How to delete duplicate rows meeting multiple conditions

Tags: r

Need some help. I have a data frame below showing gene expression counts.

Some of the genes are duplicated, and my goal is to delete the duplicates.

The tricky thing is that the duplicated genes have different expression profiles than the actual gene -- the duplicate genes always have expression values of 0 for all cells, whereas most of the cells have non-0 values. This means I can't just use `distinct()` because that function doesn't discriminate for the correct duplicate. Complicating things further, some of the non-duplicated, 'normal' genes have 0 expression in all cells, so I can't just filter out all genes with 0 expression using rowSums. Desired output is included.

Any thoughts on how I can filter out my duplicates?

```
      X cellA cellB cellC cellD celE
1  geneA     0     0     0     0    0
2  geneB     6     8     4     7    3
3  geneB     0     0     0     0    0
4  geneC     0     0     0     0    0
5  geneC     4     5     6     7    8
6  geneC     0     0     0     0    0
7  geneD     0     0     0     0    0
8  geneD     0     0     0     0    0
9  geneE     4     3     2     5    6
10 geneF     0     0     0     0    0
```

Desired output

```
      cellA cellB cellC cellD celE
geneA     0     0     0     0    0
geneB     6     8     4     7    3
geneC     4     5     6     7    8
geneD     0     0     0     0    0
geneE     4     3     2     5    6
geneF     0     0     0     0    0
```

Comment: Can you show what would be your expected output in this case?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, Ronak. Added desired output.

Comment: d.b., I tried your solution and it did not work; it did not delete the columns correctly. Does anyone know why? This looked like a great solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you could do is `arrange` the data in descending order and select the first row of each gene. Using `dplyr`, we could do it as

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   arrange_all(desc) %>%
   group_by(X) %>%
   slice(1L)

#   X     cellA cellB cellC cellD  celE
#  <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 geneA     0     0     0     0     0
#2 geneB     6     8     4     7     3
#3 geneC     4     5     6     7     8
#4 geneD     0     0     0     0     0
#5 geneE     4     3     2     5     6
#6 geneF     0     0     0     0     0
```

and in base R, that would be

```
df1 <- df[do.call(order, c(df, decreasing = TRUE)), ]
df2 <- df1[!duplicated(df1$X), ]
df2[order(df2$X), ]
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak. This solution worked. I appreciate your help.